# What mathematical areas lie at the interface of analysis, algebra and geometry?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, geometry, soft-question

Would it be some area that draws on many fields such as algebraic geometry? Is there some sort of unification of these three fields?

Comment: Which area in mathematics would draw on the greatest number of other fields in math? I've always heard that algebraic geometry does, is this true?

Comment: I think, number theory even more. FLT is one example only, where many areas of mathematics have been used.

Answer (score 1):

Consider: Differential Geometry, Algebraic Topology, Algebraic Geometry for example.

Comment: As in lying at the intersection of all three fields

Comment: hmmm. . .  yeap!

Comment: Is there a field that unifies these three fields? And how does, say, algebraic topology draw on analytic techniques naturally, except in special cases? Or differential geometry from algebra? Algebraic geometry does indeed have an analytic viewpoint as in Griffiths-Harris.

Comment: in other hand the axiomatic-deductive method allows to unify algebro-analytic-geometric phenomena

Comment: Could you please expand? Which field would involve all three of these most naturally? Would it be just algebraic geometry?

Comment: one that is a "little" field of study that all the time handles algebro-analytic-geometric techniques it is dubbed   **Low Dimensional Topology**

Comment: Is there a list of any other such fields? Would this include algebraic geometry since one can also approach it from an analytic viewpoint?

Comment: there are http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/math

Comment: Which one of those categories?

Comment: do you read each label there?

Comment: Yes, it's not obvious which one naturally incorporates all three fields though.

Comment: . . you are right

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there is a branch of algebraic geometry whose focus is on complex algebraic varieties(with some technical property in addition).

One can look at its local properties by using complex manifold theory(GEOMETRY) and several variable complex analysis(ANALYSIS). Also, one can use abstract algebraic geometry(ALGEBRA) theory to look at its other properties.

A classical examples of this is the theory of Riemann surfaces, which is an one dimensional complex manifold with algebraic structure.

Comment: Are there any other such areas? Or is algebraic geometry the most natural one that ties in with these three areas?

Comment: I cannot say this is "THE" one, but it is definitely what most people would think of.

Comment: Are there natural analytic techniques used in algebraic topology or algebraic in differential topology/geometry? Don't number theory and lie algebras/ lie groups fit too?

Comment: There are, but not the main theme in these topics.

Comment: Oh thanks. Finally, is there any sort of unification for these areas as well? Would it be something like the Langlands program and its geometric counterpart? Does this fit with algebraic geometry in any way?

Comment: I am not an expert on Langlands program but I vaguely remember from a previous it is indeed kind of a unification of these areas. Maybe you can tell me more after looking into it. :)